# How to authenticate with node.js Passport through a get-request?

Tags: node.js, middleware

I am using Passport-Local (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) to authenticate with node.js. So far this example works like a charm, since the users are logging in thorugh a post-webform:

```
app.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
});
```

Now, however, I want to code up a JSON-based API to authenticate users by calling a particular URL. Modifying the code block to `app.get(…` doesn't work though.

Any advice?

Comment: Update: Seems passport is using `req.body` for username/password. If I hack passport-local to use `req.query` it works. Not my preferred method of doing it though…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, and solved it by adding this to my route handler for login:

```
req.body = req.query;
```

Maybe not the perfect solution, but it's certainly better than hacking passport. ;)

Also note that there's a pending request in passport-local to fix this problem: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/pull/12

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://github.com/yarax/passport-url strategy will be useful for you

It allows to authenticate users with a token giving by GET request

```
var url = new UrlStrategy({
    failRedirect : "/login",
    varName : "secret"
}, function (secret, done) { // put your check logic here
    if (secret == 'foo') done(null, {id:'bar'});
    else done("wrong");
});

passport.use(url);
```

Comment: This question is rather outdated, given it is about to have its third anniversary :-) Thanks for your reply anyways!